# Use Enum property in WebAPI method input Dto

Tags: c#, enums, asp.net-core-webapi, dto

Lets assume that we have a WebAPI that contains a method **GetCustomers**. This method accepts an input Dto. On of the properties of the Dto is an **enum** **CustomerType**.

I made an HttpRequest to this WebAPI method, and i passed an integer value for the property **CustomerType**

The code works fine, but my question is, should there be a reason where i should define the property **CustomerType** to be **CustomerTypeId** of type **int** instead of defining it as an **enum**. Know that i have access to the Enum since its in a shared project.

Is there a best practice where we should use values or enums in Dto's?

Comment: What exactly is the content of your field? If you only need this field to display the int value, then you do not need to use the enum type to bind. Enum is a value type data type, which is used to declare a list of named integer constants.
Therefore, if this field needs to be bound to the content corresponding to the int value, then you still need to use enum to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enum in this case is absolutely fine, but if you use this property only to store a value and you aren't going to use it in any program logic then int could be good enough.

When would you consider to use an int property over an enum? For example when the values come from a different source and you are not 100% sure about the possible values.

Another case when int could work better is when the CustomerType would have some additional data attached. In this case values with metadata are often stored in the database. Even here enum could work as good as int, but both places should be keep in sync to make sure enum values always point correct values from database. It's realy important when enum values are used by names in your code as it will help to avoid annoying and often hard to find bugs.